# Django/Tastypie Image upload - Invalid boundary in multipart: None?

Tags: django, python-2.7, tastypie, multipartform-data

I am new to python/django/tastypie and am trying to do a file upload. I am getting a very strange (to me it is) error that I can not seem to figure out. Whenever I try to upload a photo via my rest client (CocoaRest Client), it bombs with the following error:

```
{
  "error_message" : "Invalid boundary in multipart: None",
  "traceback" : "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/Users/crown/Documents/Sources/Virtualenvs/GOCApi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/crown/Documents/Sources/GOCApi/api/resources/member.py\", line 85, in post_profile_picture\n    if('image' in request.FILES):\n\n  File \"/Users/crown/Documents/Sources/Virtualenvs/GOCApi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py\", line 214, in _get_files\n    self._load_post_and_files()\n\n  File \"/Users/crown/Documents/Sources/Virtualenvs/GOCApi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py\", line 217, in _load_post_and_files\n    self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)\n\n  File \"/Users/crown/Documents/Sources/Virtualenvs/GOCApi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py\", line 176, in parse_file_upload\n    parser = MultiPartParser(META, post_data, self.upload_handlers, self.encoding)\n\n  File \"/Users/crown/Documents/Sources/Virtualenvs/GOCApi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py\", line 69, in __init__\n    raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary)\n\nMultiPartParserError: Invalid boundary in multipart: None\n"
}
```

I have the header set "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" as well as have a file added to the files tab.

Here is my method that I am calling from the client:

```
def post_profile_picture(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if(request.method == 'POST'):
            if(str(request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']) != "multipart/form-data"):
                return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("Unsupported media type"), response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)
            else:
                if('image' in request.FILES):

                    #bunch of code removed

                    return self.create_response(request, {"profile_img" : profile_img_key_name, "thumb_img" : thumb_img_key_name}, response_class=http.HttpResponse)
                else:
                    return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("No image found"), response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("Method not allowed"), response_class=http.HttpMethodNotAllowed)
```

When I do a print(request) before if('image' in request.FILES), I do not get that same error, it actually jumps to my else and prints "No image found", which is strange that it wouldn't blow up the same way.

I'm not sure what else I need to do, add more headers? set a "boundary" (not sure what that is)... any help is much appreciated. I am willing to try things out and post results on here for better assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ended up making a new ModelResource and then setting the Content-Type to: multipart/form-data; boundary=frontier

Took me a while to figure this out, even though the OP was yesterday, 10 hours is a lot of googling and trial and error... smdh.

Here is the Model Resource:

```
from tastypie import http, fields
from django.conf.urls import url
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from api.helper_methods import HelperMethods
from django.conf import settings
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import cStringIO
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

class FileUploadResource(ModelResource):
    img = fields.FileField(attribute="img", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = 'post'
        resource_name = 'file_upload'
        include_resource_uri = False

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('get_profile_picture'), name="api_get_profile_picture"),
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/profile_picture/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('post_profile_picture'), name="api_post_profile_picture"),
            ]

    def get_profile_picture(self, request, **kwargs):
        return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("Bad requested"), response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)

    def post_profile_picture(self, request, **kwargs):
        if(request.method == 'POST'):
            if "multipart/form-data" not in str(request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']):
                return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("Unsupported media type"), response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)
            else:
                if('image' in request.FILES):
                    upload = request.FILES['image']
                    main_img = Image.open(upload)

                    profile_img = main_img.resize((200,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                    profile_img_io = cStringIO.StringIO()
                    profile_img.save(profile_img_io, 'PNG', quality=85)

                    thumb_img = main_img.resize((80,80), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                    thumb_img_io = cStringIO.StringIO()
                    thumb_img.save(thumb_img_io, 'PNG', quality=85)

                    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
                    bucket = conn.get_bucket(settings.BUCKET_NAME)

                    profile_img_key_name = HelperMethods.generate_pic_key() + ".png"
                    profile_img_key = Key(bucket)
                    profile_img_key.key = profile_img_key_name
                    profile_img_key.set_contents_from_string(profile_img_io.getvalue())
                    profile_img_key.make_public()

                    thumb_img_key_name = HelperMethods.generate_pic_key() + ".png"
                    thumb_img_key = Key(bucket)
                    thumb_img_key.key = thumb_img_key_name
                    thumb_img_key.set_contents_from_string(thumb_img_io.getvalue())
                    thumb_img_key.make_public()

                    return self.create_response(request, {"profile_img" : profile_img_key_name, "thumb_img" : thumb_img_key_name}, response_class=http.HttpResponse)
                else:
                    return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("No image found"), response_class=http.HttpBadRequest)
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, HelperMethods.api_return_msg("Method not allowed"), response_class=http.HttpMethodNotAllowed)
```

It also uses amazon s3 to store the images after PIL is used to change the image.